# bootstrap chain-index.db

Tags: plutus-pab

The process to sync the plutus-pab chain-index for the testnet takes over 3+ days now and will take longer as time goes on.   Is it possible to bootstrap the chain-index sync process to reduce the manual sync process?  I've tried copying over the chain-index.db (and referencing that file in the chain-index-config.json  file) that was already sync'd from another machine, but it appears to be starting over again. Thank you.

Comment: Copying over chain-index.db should work. What exacly are you running on the command line?

Comment: Thanks for confirming.   The command I am running is from the plutus-pab/test-node readme.   cabal exec -- plutus-chain-index --config testnet/chain-index-config.json start-index.

Answer (score 0):

Chain-index tries to use the existing db file, but if anything goes wrong it just starts over, so it's hard to diagnose. It could be a version difference. Or it could be a silly mistake, but without error it's hard to say.

You could try simple things like running it for a bit on the new machine and copying the file over to the old machine and see if it picks that up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes, it is a differen't version of chain-index that I am trying to bootstrap, so most likely that is what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that syncing chain-index.db is faster on a Linux in a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) than in a standalone Linux. This might be caused of a better virtual memory manager on Windows or some special compiled-in kernel features.

On my Windows 11 Home / WSL2 Ubuntu-20.04 system with 16 GB RAM and AMD Ryzen 5 3500U 2.10 GHz processor and SSD, syncing on 2022-04-20 took *about 14 hours*.

Kernel version of my WSL2 (*uname -r*): `5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2` of 2021-06-07, see [Kernel Updates](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Windows%20Subsystem%20for%20Linux%20Update).